# Apache PIG Records Count

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am running `PIG` script using `Java API` (`pigserver.registerscript`)
I need to find out number of records processed and number of output records
using `java API`.
How to implement the same.

I have simple pig script as follows

```
A = LOAD '$input_file_path' USING PigStorage('$') as (id:double,name:chararray,code:int);
Dump A;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE PigUdf2(id),name;
Dump B;
```

& java code is .....

```
PigStats ps;
HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap();
Path p = new Path("/home/shweta/Desktop/debugging_pig_udf/pig_in");
m.put("input_file_path", p.toString()); PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);
pigServer.registerScript("/home/shweta/Desktop/debugging_pig_udf/pig_script.pig‌​",m);
```

I need to find out Input records and output records COUNT using java API

Comment: show us some code and we can help you evolve

Comment: add the code in your question please and format it pl